# raspberry pi pico w, trying to send http request

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

I was trying to place a http request using the library given in
https://github.com/peterharperuk/pico-examples/commit/450a4d51ae1dd5f571e06c636b1fda1ba80f6ace

every time getting this logs, probably the connection is getting closed

```
resolving worldtimeapi.org
DNS resolving complete
connecting to server IP 213.188.196.246 port 80
tls_client_err -15
```

I haven't made any changes in the given library just added the files and run. I don't know where I am going wrong. can any one help me on this.

I expect the tls_client_recv callback should print the requested page